# spinner cargando... NO funciona Css

Tags: css

Tengo un css que quiero usar para que aparezca cuando el usuario tiene que esperar la carga de una función. Un Cargando de toda la vida. EL css lo uso en otra web y me funciona bien, pero en esta solo se ve el circulo estático y no hace la función de gif digamos. Estoy usando el navegador google crhome

EL css es este:

```
/* Spiner*/
#cargando {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999999999;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Cuando yo creo el div `<div id="cargando"></div>` en la web solo me aparece el circulo estático. No se a que se puede deber.

Comment: ¿El css de la animación también lo copiaste `pulsate`?

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, entiendo que solo hay esto de código no? No Necesita nada mas para funcionar.

Comment: Tienes razón, falta código. Respondo a mi pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Faltaba este trozo de código css

```
@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
      transform: scale(.1);
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1.2);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Pido disculpas